# How to set up MongoDB to be used with Sublime Text 3

Tags: mongodb, ide, sublimetext3, sublimetext

So I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPLWpCcYkfU) to set up Sublime Text 3 to use MongoDB. Here's what I did.

I followed [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uFY60CESlM&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDQ5DrbIl20Zu9hx1IjeVhO&index=1) to install MongoDB and get it up and running.

I opened Sublime Text 3. I clicked Tools > Build System > New Build System. It opened a file named `untitled.sublime-build` which had the following contents:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "make"
}
```

I changed it to

```
{
    "selector":"source.js",
    "shell":"true",
    "cmd":["C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin/mongo", "<", "$file"]
}
```

Then I saved the file as `custom.sublime-build`.

Then I opened a new `.js` file and typed `Math.round(Math.random()*100);` and built it by Ctrl+B. **I got the following errors**.

```
2016-06-21T02:08:11.961+0500 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is not installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test
2016-06-21T02:08:13.144+0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2016-06-21T02:08:13.187+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
[Finished in 2.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin/mongo', '<', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Tests\\jss.js']]
[dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\Tests]
[path: C:\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;]
```

**What should I do to solve this problem and successfully setup Sublime Text 3 to work for MongoDB?**

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test
Connection issue .... not able to establish connection , 
Can you check mongodb is running or not by checking in command prompt with below command -mongod
>> mongod

Comment: Did you create folder - \data\db” folder in C:/ for mongodb to store data

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yep, I did.

Comment: @NagaSaiA I run `mongo` which gave me `C:\Users\Kapau>mongo
2016-06-21T02:50:53.558+0500 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update
is not installed, will zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test`

Comment: @NagaSaiA Then I run `db`, which gave `test`. Then I entered `mongod >> mongod` as you suggested, and got `> db
test
> mongod >> mongod
2016-06-21T02:51:15.379+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: mongod is not
defined :
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: Typing `mongod` inside of `mongo` shell should not do anything, because it is not a command.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check that you have MongoDB server running that you can connect to. Test by connecting via [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/).

2) Change your `sublime-build` file to escape the Windows path properly.

```
{
   "selector": "source.js",
   "shell": true, 
   "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.2\\bin\\mongo", "<", "$file"]
}
```

Note the double back-slashes.

3) Make sure the javascript file is saved, so that `$file` resolved to a path.

Answer (score 0):

for sublime with zip version add your build file to Sublime3XX\Data\Packages\User
folder and restart your sublime text editor u can see your build file in Tools->Build Systems